# regex in js ,get the value from cookie

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the "value" for the "key" in cookie,the cookie's format is:

> key1:value1;key2:value2;......keyn:valuen

Because JS doesn't support `(?<=exp)`, I  use this function to get the value:

```
    function getCookieValue(key)
    {
        var cookie = document.cookie;
        var filter = new RegExp(key+"=([^;]*)(;|$)");
        return cookie.match(filter)[1];
    }
```

The result is correct, but I have some questions:

1. If I use `cookie.match(filter)`, the match result is `key:value;,value`. The regex matched two result. Why?
2. For `cookie.match(filter)[1]`，is the returned array dependent on the JS parser?
3. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Yes, there’s a better approach: parse the entire cookie at once into an object, and take properties out of that.

Comment: Is the `=` in your code supposed to be a `:`?

Comment: sorry ,i was wrong,the cookie format is:

Comment: key1=value1;key2=value2;......keyn=valuen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if i use cookie.match(filter) ,the match result is "key:value;,value". the rex matched two result,why?

Resulting value from `String#match` function is an array with first index of array holding the full match and subsequent elements in array holding your matched groups.

> For cookie.match(filter)[1]，is the returned array dependent on the JS parser?

No that is not dependent upon a specific JS parser, that behavior is standard.

> Is there a better approach?

I am sure there are cookie parser libraries out there.

Comment: thanks ,i find a plugin "jquery.cookie.js" in github,but i want to know is there any problem in my code ? After all,it is easier.I have tested in chrome ,safari,FF,it's ok .